# Evaluate arithmetic expression recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I need help with evaluating arithmetic expression (INFIX) via recursion. I made a tree, scanning from right to left (+,- first, *,/ second). The error is:

> For input string: "2+3"

I don't what I'm doing wrong. I was hoping if someone can look at my method and point me to right direction please. Appreciate the help. Here is my method.

```
   // recursive method to evaluate an expression given by string s 
int evaluateE(String s)
{   
    String r1;
    String r2;
    int result = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-')
            break;
        else if (s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/')
            break;
    }

    r1 = s.substring(0, i);
    r2 = s.substring(i + 1, s.length());

    //Base case
    if(!r1.contains("+") && !r1.contains("-") && !r1.contains("*") && !r1.contains("/") &&
       !r2.contains("+") && !r2.contains("-") && !r2.contains("*") && !r2.contains("/"))
            return Integer.parseInt(s);

    switch (s.charAt(i))
    {
        case '+':
            result =  evaluateE(r1) + evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = evaluateE(r1) - evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = evaluateE(r1) * evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (Integer.parseInt(r2) == 0)  //if denominator is zero
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid divisor");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            else
                result = evaluateE(r1) / evaluateE(r2);
                break;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Tell us what are you expecting, what is the result and why it's not 'working'. Can you provide also some test cases ?

Comment: I'm inputing INFIX expression. I'm trying simple stuff like 2+3+4. It's saying that error at "For input string: "2+3"

Comment: add error message into original

Comment: use blockquote instead of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking the operators, if they contain an operator, i.e. for `r1+r2` you check, if `r1` or `r2` contain a operator. If your `String` contains exactly 1 operator, neither `r1` nor `r2` contain a operator and therefore `Integer.parse(s)` will be executed. Since `s = r1 + operator + r2` contains the operator, `Integer.parse` will throw an error.

To fix this, check the base case before doing anything else in that method:

```
int evaluateE(String s) {
    //Base case
    if (!s.contains("+") && !s.contains("-") && !s.contains("*") && !s.contains("/")) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    int i;

    for (i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            break;
        } else if (s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/') {
            break;
        }
    }

    String r1 = s.substring(0, i);
    String r2 = s.substring(i + 1, s.length());

    int result = 0;

    switch (s.charAt(i)) {
        case '+':
            result = evaluateE(r1) + evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = evaluateE(r1) - evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = evaluateE(r1) * evaluateE(r2);
            break;
        case '/':
            int right = evaluateE(r2);
            if (right == 0) //if denominator is zero
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid divisor");
                System.exit(1);
            } else {
                result = evaluateE(r1) / right;
            }
            break;
    }
    return result;

}
```

That ignores operator precedence however, i.e. it evaluates expressions from left to right. E.g. `10-3*6/9+4` is interpreted as `(((10-3)*6)/9)+4`.

If you want to take operator precedence into accout, you have to ignore `*` or `/`, if there is a `+` or a `-` in the string. This would require you to modify your for loop:

```
    // search for '+' and '-' first
    for (i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-') {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < 0) {
        // if '+' and '-' were not found, search for '*' and '/'
        for (i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '*' || s.charAt(i) == '/') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Brown123 That's an issue with operator precedence and using my code you'd get `8` and not `4`. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you are returning `Integer.parseInt(s)` when in all likelihood s will have an operator (`+`,`-`,`*` or `/`). So, essentially you are trying to convert `"2+3"` into an `int`, which is the reason for the error.